# Highlighting Spock test keywords in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, spock

I am using Eclipse for a Java project with some tests written in Groovy / Spock which uses the `given:` `when:` `then:` syntax.  I would like these keywords to highlighted with some colour.  Note: the spock plugin is supposed to this but doesn't work.  So wanted to just do this myself.

Comment: Install plugins for the syntaxe you use. Preferences > install Software >....

Comment: Have you looked at the Groovy Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @Pyves yes, nothing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`given:`, `when:`, etc. are statement labels.  There is currently no support for highlighting statement labels in Groovy-Eclipse.  They are actually a bit tricky to pin down since they are not saved in the AST with source position information.  `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.Statement.getStatementLabels()` returns `List<String>`.  So it is possible to tell which statements have labels, but then the source range of the statement would need to be scanned to find the range of the label.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is not any support for the label in Groovy. I have done some search but as @emilles said, there is nothing on the web.

If you have the grammar file or can get it somewhere (I did not find it after some search), transform it into a HRC File then follow the step under. See there (http://colorer.sourceforge.net/hrc-ref/index.html)

Now, you could just create the coloring for your language. There are many plugin out there for doing this like EclipseColorer. I have already use that one, so I gonna give you the step :

```
1 - Install the software (Help -> Install New Software)
2 - Search http://colorer.sf.net/eclipsecolorer/
3 - Once the plugin is installed and Eclipse is restart
4 - Copy the HRC file in the eclipse's folder
5 - Add the prototype file
```

The basic one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='Windows-1251'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hrc PUBLIC
 "-//Cail Lomecb//DTD Colorer HRC take5//EN"
 "http://colorer.sf.net/2003/hrc.dtd"
 >
 <hrc version="take5" xmlns="http://colorer.sf.net/2003/hrc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://colorer.sf.net/2003/hrc http://colorer.sf.net/2003/hrc.xsd"
 ><annotation><documentation>
 'auto' is a place for include
 to colorer your own HRCs
</documentation></annotation>
<prototype name="d" group="main" description="D">
 <location link="types/d.hrc"/>
 <filename>/.(d)$/i</filename>
 </prototype>
</hrc>


6 - In Eclipse Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations
7 - Add the filetype for your syntax
8 - Restart Eclipse and your good
```

If you dont have this kind of file is gonna be long and difficult, it's a domain specific language and you have to start from the beginning. So the only real method to do this, it's by creating a new coloring syntax for your need but it's very tricky to achieve.

You have some information there about it : http://www.mo-seph.com/projects/syntaxhighlighting